# Are hierarchal states/fractional exchange statistics equivalent in the FQHE?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-hall-effect, algebraic-topology

There are several theories for the [fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect#History_and_developments). The last listed in the Wikipedia article are composite fermions, though these seem to be a subset of fractional exchange statistics:

A finite group of anyons has some [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(mathematics)) that defines their Cayley graph. But you can view $n$ vortices as a [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(topology)), whose universal cover is a Cayley graph.  The former is more general.

What about a hierarchy of states? You can generalize the idea of a boundary in algebraic toplogy to use some character, similar to the [immanant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanant) (also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4740912/378720)). I want to say that every local conformation can be described by an immanant, i.e. character, but I'm not sure.